# Display some images in php files by getting the images from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I can display images in html form like below..here these images are in images folder

```
<div id="thumbs" class="navigation">
  <ul class="thumbs noscript">
  <li><a class="thumb" href="images/disease1.jpg" title="Title #0">Title #0</a></li>
  <li><a class="thumb" href="images/disease2.jpg" title="Title #1">Title #1</a></li>
  </ul>
<div>
```

But I want to display images in php file by getting imagges from the database according to above format.my mysql database has more than 1 images for an id.so I want to dispay images according to the id.

Below is what I've tried. Here's my PHP file:

```
<?php
$value=$_GET['val'];
$set_photos=mysql_query("SELECT * from photos where idProblem='$value'",$connection);

if(!$set_prob) {
    die("database query failed".mysql_error());   
}

$num_photos=mysql_num_rows($set_photos);

for($i=1;$i<=$num_photos;$i++) {
    $get_photos='<div id="thumbs"><li><a class=\"thumb"\ href=\".$photo."\ title=\"Title.$i."\>photo </a></li></div>';
}
?>
```

This is the PHP file where I'm trying to display the images by running the above PHP file:

```
<div id="thumbs" class="navigation">
<ul class="thumbs noscript">
<?php echo $get_photos; ?></ul></div>
```

I'm trying to find out what's wrong here. How can solve this issue?

Comment: when you run the above file what error are you getting ?

Comment: here is the error I got..Notice: Undefined variable: get_photos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi try below code it solve your issue :)

```
<?php
$value=$_GET['val'];
$set_photos = mysql_query("SELECT * from photos where idProblem='".$value."'", $connection);

$liList = '';
$ind = 0;
if(mysql_num_rows($set_photos))
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($set_photos))
    {
        $liList .= '<li><a class="thumb" href="'.$row['YOUR_IMAGE_PATH_FIELD_NAME'].'" title="Title #'.$ind.'">Title #'.$ind.'</a></li>';
        $ind++;
    }
}
?>

<div id="thumbs" class="navigation">
    <ul class="thumbs noscript">
    <?php echo $liList; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to display them as you pull them out of the database:

This is simply overwriting the variable `$get_photos`

```
for($i=1;$i<=$num_photos;$i++) {
$get_photos='
    <div id="thumbs">
        <li>
            <a class=\"thumb"\ href=\".$photo."\ title=\"Title.$i."\>photo </a>
        </li>
    </div>';
}
```

Change to:

```
echo '<div id="thumbs" class="navigation"><ul class="thumbs noscript">';

for($i=1;$i<=$num_photos;$i++) {
    echo '<li><a class="thumb" href="'.$photo.'" title="Title'.$i.'">photo </a></li>';
}

echo '</ul></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the query returns rows, because it seems that for statement is not executing